# RegexKit and RegexKitLite with Xcode 4 gets "Semantic Issue" errors/warnings

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, regexkitlite, regexkit

I am using Xcode 4.3 on Mac OS X 10.7.3. Base SDK and Deployment is OS X 10.6.

When I use RegexKitLite, I get lots of compiler warnings: *'Semantic Issue'*
**Passing 'void *volatile __strong *' to parameter of type 'void *__strong *' discards qualifiers**

and
**Passing 'void *volatile __strong *' to parameter of type 'void *__strong *volatile' discards qualifiers**

Although they appear harmless, it is very annoying since I basically strive for zero warnings. There is no update to RegexKitLite since 2010/04/18, and no discussions about issues with Xcode 4 on sourceforge. With Xcode 3.2, I did not get those warnings.

Is there a way to turn off all warnings only for RegexKitLite?
Or an update to RegexKitLite?

I also attempted to install the framework RegexKit instead of RegexKitLite, but that package has not been updated since 2008/01/29, and instructions for install don't apply to Xcode 4, and there are no sourceforge discussions about issues, and not really elsewhere from what I have seen. Since the RegexKit framework is more powerful than the Lite version, I got interested in it, and at [iPhone: RegexKit vs. RegexKit lite - going through an array takes very very long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240789/iphone-regexkit-vs-regexkit-lite-going-through-an-array-takes-very-very-long) the author of these packages says that RegexKit outperforms the Lite version because it has many optimizations.

Nevertheless, I installed RegexKit framework using hints from [How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4) and  http://www.thinketg.com/Company/Blogs/11-03-20/Xcode_4_Tips_Adding_frameworks_to_your_project.asp

However, I get *'Semantic Issue'* also here, but now these are errors in the header file, and not just warnings:
**Pointer to function type 'NSString *' may not be 'restrict' qualified**

So it won't even compile!

Is the RegexKit framework not even compatible with Xcode 4?

I have found no info on this, except the link http://www.ohloh.net/p/AGP-Launcher/commits/126607585 which said that he "Changed to RegexKitLite as RegexKit isn't supported in XCode 4".

Comment: Obviously no response.

A friend of mine spoke to the developer of these packages recently, and there was no suggestion of any need to update RegexKitLite he said. Hmm, too bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With clang, I silenced the warnings as follows:

At the top of RegexKitLite.m:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wincompatible-pointer-types"
```

And at the bottom:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```